# Convolution, Gaussianity and Polynomial Phase

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

If we have a Gaussian pulse $f(t)$ in time , its Fourier Transform $F(\omega)$ is a Gaussian pulse. Consider the following **polynomial phase function** in the frequency domain, that is $$G(\omega) = e^{j(a_0+a_1\omega+a_2\omega^2+...a_n \omega^n)}$$

***EDIT**: Note that $a_0,..,a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a_n \neq 0$*

Now if we take the product of the Fourier Transforms $F(\omega)$ and $G(\omega)$, and then take the inverse Fourier of this product,
will we get a Gaussian time pulse for any order $n$?

Is $h(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{F(\omega) \cdot G(\omega)\}(t) = f(t) * g(t)$ Gaussian?

I know for sure this is **true for polynomials of order 0**(due to linearity), **1**(due to the time shift property) **and** **2**(due to some notes in Optical Communications).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would $g$ look like if $\Re a_3 \ne 0$ and $a_4 = a_5 = \cdots = 0$?

Comment: I am interested in the case where all coefficients $a_0,...,a_n$ are real, so allow me to edit the question. I only know the Fourier transform of $g(t)$, I am not sure.